# For "Viewing an email" Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a web automation using the Selenium library in Python language.
I wrote the code to open the incoming email but it gives an error.
I tried with "id","xpath", "title" but it failed.

For Example İmage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xz0T.png)

Code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/i[2]').click()
```

#Array

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="a009b4f3-48b0-53f7-1a84-b1823cefcd25"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
  File "C:\Python\ProtonMailAçma\Hotmail
```

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is thrown because there is no element with `id=a009b4f3-48b0-53f7-1a84-b1823cefcd25` in your example screen shot. In your screen shot, id is `9618...7e71`.

Comment: Maybe your element is in iframe?

Comment: That ID is likely generated and changes often so it won't be a good locator. You'll need to find another way to locate the element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. This includes HTML.